# AWS Sample Template: S3_Website_With_CloudFront_Distribution.template Fails Upon Start do to Route 53 Domain Name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudfront

I am working with the AWS Samples templates from [enter link description here](https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-templates-us-west-1/S3_Website_With_CloudFront_Distribution.template) where I reduced the mapping a little, but leaving everything else as is.  In review the code, and reading the notes within the template, it appears that I should be able to run the code by simply entering the name of the Host Zone which I have registered with Route 53, within the parameter field when running the stack. I also created the certificate via the ACM.

However, I am getting, however, the following error:

To add an alternate domain name (CNAME) to a CloudFront distribution, you must attach a trusted certificate that validates your authorization to use the domain name. For more details, see: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html#alternate-domain-names-requirements (Service: AmazonCloudFront; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidViewerCertificate; Request ID: ---------)

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion" : "2010-09-09",

  "Description" : "AWS CloudFormation Sample Template S3_Website_With_CloudFront_Distribution: Sample template showing how to create a website with a custom DNS name, hosted on Amazon S3 and served via Amazone CloudFront. It assumes you already have a Hosted Zone registered with Amazon Route 53. **WARNING** This template creates an Amazon Route 53 DNS record, an S3 bucket and a CloudFront distribution. You will be billed for the AWS resources used if you create a stack from this template.",

  "Parameters" : {
    "HostedZone" : {
      "Type" : "String",
      "Description" : "The DNS name of an existing Amazon Route 53 hosted zone",
      "AllowedPattern" : "(?!-)[a-zA-Z0-9-.]{1,63}(?<!-)",
      "ConstraintDescription" : "must be a valid DNS zone name."
    }
  },

  "Mappings" : {
    "Region2S3WebsiteSuffix": {
      "us-east-1"      : { "Suffix": ".s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com" }
    }

  },

  "Resources" : {
    "S3BucketForWebsiteContent" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::S3::Bucket",
      "Properties" : {
        "AccessControl" : "PublicRead",
        "WebsiteConfiguration" : {
           "IndexDocument" : "index.html",
           "ErrorDocument" : "error.html"
        }
      }
    },

    "WebsiteCDN" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::CloudFront::Distribution",
      "Properties" : {
         "DistributionConfig" : {
           "Comment" : "CDN for S3-backed website",
           "Aliases" : [{ "Fn::Join" : [ "", [{"Ref" : "AWS::StackName"}, {"Ref" : "AWS::AccountId"}, ".", {"Ref" : "AWS::Region"}, ".", { "Ref" : "HostedZone" }]]}],
           "Enabled" : "true",
       "DefaultCacheBehavior" : {
         "ForwardedValues" : { "QueryString" : "true" },
         "TargetOriginId" : "only-origin",
         "ViewerProtocolPolicy" : "allow-all"
       },
           "DefaultRootObject" : "index.html",
       "Origins" : [
         { "CustomOriginConfig" : 
                 {
                   "HTTPPort" : "80",
                   "HTTPSPort" : "443",
                   "OriginProtocolPolicy" : "http-only"
                 },
               "DomainName" : { "Fn::Join" : ["", [{"Ref" : "S3BucketForWebsiteContent"},
                                                   {"Fn::FindInMap" : [ "Region2S3WebsiteSuffix", {"Ref" : "AWS::Region"}, "Suffix" ]}]]},
           "Id" : "only-origin"
             }]
         }
      }
    },

    "WebsiteDNSName" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::Route53::RecordSet",
      "Properties" : {
        "HostedZoneName" : { "Fn::Join" : [ "", [{ "Ref" : "HostedZone" }, "."]]},
        "Comment" : "CNAME redirect custom name to CloudFront distribution",
        "Name" : { "Fn::Join" : [ "", [{"Ref" : "AWS::StackName"}, {"Ref" : "AWS::AccountId"}, ".", {"Ref" : "AWS::Region"}, ".", { "Ref" : "HostedZone" }]]},
        "Type" : "CNAME",
        "TTL" : "900",
        "ResourceRecords" : [{ "Fn::Join" : [ "", ["http://", {"Fn::GetAtt" : ["WebsiteCDN", "DomainName"]} ]]}]
      }
    }
  },

  "Outputs" : {
    "WebsiteURL" : {
      "Value" : {"Fn::Join" : [ "", ["http://", {"Ref" : "WebsiteDNSName"} ]] },
      "Description" : "The URL of the newly created website"
    },
    "BucketName" : {
      "Value" : { "Ref" : "S3BucketForWebsiteContent" },
      "Description" : "Name of S3 bucket to hold website content"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you should have an SSL certificate for the alternate domain that you are trying to add. You can request an `ACM` public certificate in `us-east-1` region.

I suggest you set up the ACM certificate outside the cloudformation, because creating an ACM certificate requires manual DNS/Email verification.

Hope this helps.

Reference:

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-invalid-viewer-certificate/

Comment: Yes, I believe that is correct as well.  I did create a public certificate via the ACM for the Host Zone in question.  Finally broke down and submitted a ticket with AWS Support, and they were able to duplicate the issue with my cert & zone information.  Waiting to post the their findings.